# Configure an Elasticsearch cluster with 3 Master nodes and 33 Data nodes on physical servers

Tags: elasticsearch, cluster-computing, production

I'm using Elasticsearch to deal with 10T, so I do all the work on how many shards, RAM, CPU and hard disk to use but as I try to configure these nodes , I'm very confusing with the number of feature to deal with and why we must use it , so if there is some guidelines or recommendations on how to do a standard configuration and best practice on this subject and if I need to configure other nodes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It heavily depends on your use case: is it [indexing](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/tune-for-indexing-speed.html) or [search](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/tune-for-search-speed.html) heavy, what is the document schema, what search queries are you going to run. For example, n-gram tokens might easily inflate resources needed 10x.

There are few general rules though.

- You want your shards to be between 20-50 GB
- You want less than 20k shards in your cluster
- You want shards to be distributed evenly across machines
- You want ~30 GB heap
- You want your heap to take ~50% of RAM
- You want as much CPU as you can eat
- You want local (not network-attached) SSDs

Or, if you want the least hassle possible, you can go with [Elastic Cloud](https://cloud.elastic.co/pricing) which will take some of the hardware concerns away in exchange for a fee.

Comment: what's the best way to configure my 3 master node

Comment: When you have 3 master-eligible nodes, they will vote for one of them to be master node, you don't need to sett up anything special.